# PHP JSON not displaying MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, json

The PHP I created retrieve data from a MySQL database and turns it into a JSON which is then echoed. I had 300 records and the PHP was able to display the JSON and was visible when viewed.

However, I added another 100 records to the same table and for some reason the JSON isn't being displayed. It just appears blank with no error. But when I remove the 100 records, the JSON displays as normal.

I haven't touched the PHP file during this. What could the reason be?

```
<?PHP
    include_once("connection.php");

$query = "select id,mosque_name,latitude,longitude from mosques;"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["mosques"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $mosque = array();
        $mosque["id"] = $row["id"];
        $mosque["mosque_name"] = $row["mosque_name"];
        $mosque["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
        $mosque["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];

        array_push($response["mosques"], $mosque);
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No mosques found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Could be a bunch of reasons. Maybe there's an apostrophe in the new data.

Comment: You could check [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). Your memory limit might be an issue since json_encoding does some conversion / copying of data.

Comment: Adding to @ccKep, change your php.ini settings to display_errors = On, or at the very beggining of your code, add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and check for Out of memory errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
<?PHP
    include_once("connection.php");
    $query = "select id,mosque_name,latitude,longitude from mosques;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo json_encode("");
    }
    else{
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            /*$mosque = array();
            $mosque["id"] = $row["id"];
            $mosque["mosque_name"] = $row["mosque_name"];
            $mosque["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
            $mosque["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];*/
            $fetchRow[]=$row;
           // array_push($response["mosques"], $mosque);
        }
        echo json_encode($fetchRow);
    }
   /* $response["success"] = 1;
    echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);*/
?>
```

and check your result from network